# What are the basics for creating animations in web apps?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, jquery-animate

I am looking into how to create a simple animation in an HTML5 app. I want to start with an off-page canvas (with *top* set to 100% of the window height), and animate it to the middle of the screen, above my other canvases.

I have tried Google, but the search results are a mix of animating divs and animation within a canvas, and nothing I have attempted seem to work. For example, the *jQuery animate()* function, as discussed [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

I have also tried to dynamically create a canvas and animate it on screen, but that did not work. My current code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="view-addUser" >
    <canvas id="view-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#view-addUser
{
    left: 25%;
    top: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}
```

**javaScript** (this is called when a button is pressed)

```
$("#view-addUser").animate({
    top: 100
}, 3000, function() {
    alert("animation complete");
});
```

How can I correctly get this to animate? The final result should be something like the up-direction of [this MoonBase animation](http://moonbase.com/PhDBrown/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'd recommend a library like [Tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/).**

The kind of animation you're refering to in your questions is of type "linear" i.e. you move your object from A to B at a constant rate.

A library like [Tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/) does this as well as various types of easing (the slow down/speed up effect you're showing in your example) and "elastic" algorithms.

A simple [Example](http://sole.github.io/tween.js/examples/04_simplest.html) from their site.

Comment: I'm a big fan of tween libraries but I reckon it's probably overkill for this as OP only wants to move the element up into position.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet I think "only wants to move the element up into position" is just an example to understand the basics. I'm assuming he's got a more practical usage. It'd also be less overkill than jQuery :)

Comment: Yeah fair point about jQuery - guess I just assumed he was probably already using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the position of your `div` to `absolute` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/net_uk_sweet/xYj9P/1/)):

```
#view-addUser
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The default position of elements is `static` (see [here](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/position.html)) which is no good when you're trying to animate directional properties. From the [documentation for jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Directional properties (top, right, bottom, left) have no discernible
>   effect on elements if their position style property is static, which
>   it is by default.